# Is there any difference between wood screw and anchor screws?

Tags: screws, studs, drywall-anchor

I have purchased a [screws and plug set](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/00169249/) from IKEA. However, I want to secure a bookshelf on a stud.

May I use the screws from the set? Is there any difference between screws with anchors and [wood screws](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/70224228/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anchor screws and those designed specifically for wood have very similar (if not identical) thread pitch. In fact, anchors often ship with standard pan-head wood screws. I've used them interchangeably many times.

The critical concerns are diameter (larger diameter offers substantially more holding power) and length.